# ESPV2 to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am setting up ESPv2 that will access another Cloud Run Service written in NodeJS+Express. I can Access the NodeJS+Express Service directly, but wanted to restrict access using ESPv2.

ESPv2 installs without any issue, but I have the following problem.

When I access the NodeJS+Express Cloud Run Service with ESPv2, the NodeJS+Express service trigger must use 'allow all traffic' and 'allow unauthorised invocation'.

If I restrict access to Allow Internal Traffic only, ESPv2 is not able to access the NodeJS+Express Cloud Run Service.

Should I do anything to authorise the call between ESPv2 and the called NodeJS Service?

The top part of the yaml is given below

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "APIs for managing My Site"
  version: "0.0.3"
  title: "My API"
  contact:
    email: "email@email.com"
  license:
    name: "Copyright Amzu IT Ltd"
host: "apihost-xxxx.a.run.app"
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: "apihost-xxxx.a.run.app"
    allowCors: True
x-google-backend:
  address: https://<nodejs-expess-cloud-run-url>.a.run.app
  protocol: h2
schemes:
  - "https"
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      operationId: Testing
      summary: A Test Endpoint to check if the URL is working.
      description: A Test Endpoint to check if the URL is working, does not have any security enabled for this URL.
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: "string"
      security:
        - key: []
securityDefinitions:
  key:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: x-api-key
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/REMOVED"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "REMOVED"
```

Comment: I'm about to revisit Cloud Endpoints for a project and so your question is timely. It's been some time since I last used Endpoints v2 but IIRC.... You don't want the Cloud Run service to run as `--allow-unauthenticated` (because it will and you can easily prove this to yourself). You want to restrict Cloud Run to being invoked only by the Service Account that's running the Endpoint service for you. See: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access#gcloud

Comment: I blogged about this when I tried it before (using Golang but, it should be little different). The only change is that the ESP image now includes the version (I'll update the post). See the part with `gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding`. https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/200325/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand that your ESPv2 is deployed on Cloud Run and you want to reach another Cloud Run.

- The easiest way is to deploy the NodeJS cloud run in noallow-unauthenticated mode and then to grant the ESPv2 Cloud Run service account to access to the NodeJS Cloud Run. IAM filter the traffic and only the valid traffic reach your NodeJS Cloud Run
- You can combine the previous option with a ingress=internal-only on the NodeJS Cloud Run. This time, only the authenticated (because your are in noallow-unauthenticated mode) and the traffic coming from the VPC **of the current project where NodeJS Cloud Run service is deployed**, you need to [add a serverless VPC connector to your ESPv2 Cloud Run service.](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)
- You can also have only internal traffic, but I don't recommend that, trust in IAM service is strong advantage.

I wrote [an article on that](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1), you can rely on it if you want.